# worksheet event timing causing crashes?

Tags: vba, excel

A worksheet in my Excel Doc will crash Excel occasionally, while being edited, with unhelpful error messages. Crashes are rare, but do happen. I wonder if the following part of the worksheet event code is causing the crashes. Specifically, "BeforeDoubleClick" calls "SelectionChange", but double clicking on a cell is also a selection change, so does SelectionChange get called from two different places, causing some timing issue, and sometimes a crash? I'm a beginner, don't know if I'm using the right terminology.

I have a cell (in column 1, for example) I want to toggle by colour when the user clicks on it. If I don't use the beforedoubleclick event, if a user toggles the colour, in order to toggle it again, they have to leave the cell first and go back. I'd like to avoid that, and have the user just be able to stay on that cell, toggling the colour. Similar comments for column 7.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 
If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 7 Then
   Cancel = True
Else
   Cancel = False
End If
Worksheet_SelectionChange Target
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row >= 13 And Cells(Target.Row, 2) <> "" Then
Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case xlNone
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case 4
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        UserForm2.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1       
    Case 3
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        UserForm2.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1

  End Select
End If

If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Row >= 13 And Cells(Target.Row, 2) <> ""  Then
  Set TagCell = Target 
   UserForm3.Show
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to call `Worksheet_SelectionChange` in the double-click event? Try removing it.

Otherwise you could create a separate Sub that contains the code from SelectionChange and call that Sub instead. (Call it in the SelectionChange event as well, removing it from this event.)

This way, you are running the code you need, without triggering the change event twice.

Comment: I did try it without the SelectionChange event in the double-click event, but the code does not work then (effect when clicking is just the same as if there were no code at all). Not sure why that is. Good idea about the separate Sub, will try that. Crashes are rare though, so it's a difficult experiment to do.

Comment: Not clear if this change made a difference. I finally decided to move all the selectionchange procedures to beforedoubleclick, so users just double click to toggle. So far so good.